# Does blind source separation (ICA) work if channels of mixture are observed asynchronously?

Tags: references, robust, signal-processing, independent-component-analysis, inverse-problem

Does Independent Component Analysis (ICA - fastICA, SOBI, etc.) work reliably when applied to a multidimensional mixture (observation) $X = (X^1, \cdots, X^d)$ if the different channels $X^i$ of the observation aren't recorded synchronously?

I.e., if there are time-delays between the different channels of the observation, so that instead of
$$(X^1_{t_j^1}, \cdots, X^d_{t^d_j}) \quad \text{ with } \quad t^1_j=\ldots=t^d_j \quad \forall\, j$$

one observes

$$(X^1_{t^1_j}, \cdots, X^d_{t^d_j}) \quad \text{ with } \quad t^k_j\neq t^l_j \quad (k\neq l) \quad \text{for most } j.$$

Note that in contrast to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/how-does-ica-handle-inevitable-delays-in-signals?rq=1) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/812/fail-to-separate-sound-signals-by-fastica-on-real-world-recording?noredirect=1&lq=1&newreg=38db1c2e86b94a5e834ea16bd3668253), we assume as usual that every channel observation $X^i_t$ is obtained without delays in its constituent (independent) sources $S^1, \ldots, S^d$, i.e. that $X^i_t = a_{11} S^i_t + \ldots + a_{1d} S^i_t$ for some $a_{11}, \ldots, a_{1d}\in\mathbb{R}$ at any time $t$.